# Change default Woocommerce Login and Register Page to Custom Elementor Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I have a page created using Elementor that I can use for Login and Register but it does not replace the default Woocommerce Login/Register Page when I click on endpoints that require me to login, for e.g. - Orders, Downloads, Wishlist, etc. Is there anyway I can replace the default form with the one in Elementor?

Answer (score 0):

Login and register, as well as order history is located on MyAccount page in woocommerce.

Just create your new replacement layout for myaccount page, and don't forget to go to **Woocommerce -> Settings -> Advance**. In page setup section set with MyAccount page that you just created with the elementor builder.

That should change the default login page to your new elementor page now

Answer (score -1):

For the login requirement page, you can refer to the answer given by [@byarnoldus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19739305/byarnoldus) above. For the password recovery page, you can refer to another thread "**[WooCommerce lost password form on another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29568813/woocommerce-lost-password-form-on-another-page)**". Look for the answer given by [@Polar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3721822/polar). He/she gave a step-by-step solution which you might find very helpful. I've tested it with my issue and the result is fantastic.

Hope this helps.